# Visiting UK, US passport expiring within 2 months of visit

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passports, paperwork, us-citizens

I'll be travelling to the UK (London) at the end of March for about a week from TLV. I am a dual US/Israeli citizen and will be entering the UK on my US passport, however it expires on May 7, 2017. Is this going to be a problem? Do I need to rush renew my US passport?

Comment: In that situation, they have the *option*, but not the *obligation* to exercise Paragraph 21 in a way that's unfavourable to you. Possibly Paragraph 23 would kick in. The actual result is at their discretion and hence indeterminate.

Comment: Any reason for not using the Israeli passport?

Comment: @PeterGreen You make it sound like he needs to. His US passport will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To enter the United Kingdom, a passport valid for the duration of stay is required by all nationals, except EU nationals holding a valid national ID card.

[World Travel Guide](http://www.worldtravelguide.net/united-kingdom/passport-visa)

Answer (score 1):

No, you'll be fine as long as it's valid for your whole visit.

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=us&DE=gb&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid **for the period of intended stay**.